# Redis client for C# (serviceStack) - where is the documentation?

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack.redis

The old version of [redis client for c#](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Redis/) were using commands like :

`redisClient.GetTypedClient<Customer>()`

But now  - as I've seen in examples ,  it was changed to `.As<Customer>()`

**Question**

Where is the Api-documentation for all those commands ?

*Third party links would be also appreciated*

[This link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) does not contain the documentation for all commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a full list of avilable API commands look here :

For IRedisClient API see 
https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisClient

For IRedisNativeClient API see https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisNativeClient

Comment: @RoyiNamir I've updated the wiki to include the latest API and linked to the source code of the [IRedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs) interfaces and [IRedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisNativeClient.cs) (they haven't been updated in years). `As<T>` is just a shorter and preferred alias for `GetTypedClient<T>`.